# Use dplyr in order to create a consensus column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
  Groups    Name    Category    value
        G1  A   cat1    20
        G1  A   cat2    1
        G1  B   cat3    21
        G1  B   cat3    23
        G2  B   cat4    32
        G2  C   cat2    23
        G2  C   cat2    21
```

and I wanted to add a new column `consensus_category` such as :

```
Groups  Name    Category    value   consensus_category
G1  A   cat1    20  cat2
G1  A   cat2    1   cat2
G1  B   cat3    21  cat2
G1  B   cat3    23  cat2
G2  A   cat4    32  cat4
G2  C   cat2    23  cat4
G2  C   cat2    21  cat4
```

the idea is that I have a `vector = c("A")`  with corresponds to a specific name in the dataframe

and from this name, I would like to write its corresponding `Category` for all other row in the same `Groups`, but if there is an `ex-aequo` between two `Categories`, than the winner it the `category` with the lowest `Value`. (as in the:

```
G1  A   cat1    20  cat2
G1  A   cat2    1   cat2
```

`cat2` wins because `1 < 20`

I tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  add_count(Category) %>%
  top_n(1, n) %>%
  top_n(-1, Value) %>%
  distinct(consensus_category = Category) %>%
  right_join(df)
```

but I do not know how to specify that I want as consensus guider the value in the vector `(A)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can find the `Name` which has `vec` in the group, get the minimum `value` and extract the corresponding `Category` from it. This is assuming every `Groups` would have at least one value of `vec` in it.

```
library(dplyr)

vec <- "A"

df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  mutate(consensus_category = Category[value == min(value[Name == vec])])

#  Groups Name  Category value consensus_category
#  <fct>  <fct> <fct>    <int> <fct>             
#1 G1     A     cat1        20 cat2              
#2 G1     A     cat2         1 cat2              
#3 G1     B     cat3        21 cat2              
#4 G1     B     cat3        23 cat2              
#5 G2     A     cat4        32 cat4              
#6 G2     C     cat2        23 cat4              
#7 G2     C     cat2        21 cat4
```

If there are multiple values in `vec` you might need `Name %in% vec` instead of `==`.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G2"), Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"), Category = 
c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat3", "cat4", "cat2", "cat2"), value = 
c(20L, 1L, 21L, 23L, 32L, 23L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, consensus_category := Category[value ==
      min(value[Name == vec])],  Groups]
df
#   Groups Name Category value consensus_category
#1:     G1    A     cat1    20               cat2
#2:     G1    A     cat2     1               cat2
#3:     G1    B     cat3    21               cat2
#4:     G1    B     cat3    23               cat2
#5:     G2    A     cat4    32               cat4
#6:     G2    C     cat2    23               cat4
#7:     G2    C     cat2    21               cat4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G2"), Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"), Category = 
c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat3", "cat4", "cat2", "cat2"), value = 
c(20L, 1L, 21L, 23L, 32L, 23L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -7L))
```